# Convert a List of Integers to List of String in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, jvm, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a List like `[1,2,3,4,5]` and I am trying to convert to List `["1","2","3","4","5"]`

I tried doing it like this

```
   val numbers = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
   val numbersStr = mutableListOf<String>()
   
   val itr = numbers.listIterator()
   while(itr.hasNext())
    {
        numbersStr.add(itr.next().toString())
    }
```

but I feel it is little verbose and doesnt make use of Kotlin's built in functions.

What is the best alternative?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out kotlin's [`map`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-transformations.html#map) function

```
val numberStr = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).map { it.toString() }
```

Comment: `val numberStr = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).map(Int::toString)`

Comment: It's a matter of taste whether you use a lambda or a function reference, as there's no difference in functionality, nor any practical difference in performance. Personally, I find the lambda version easier to read. It's also easier to maintain; for example, if you wanted to append ".0" to the string, you'd have to write a separate wrapper function to reference, whereas the lambda could just be tweaked to `map{ "$it.0" }`.